# how to compress json in php and decompress in android

Tags: php, android, json, compression

The purpose if the question is to compress the http response sent from php and after receieveing decompress the response and use in android.

Below is the code snippet of the php file running locally.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
$str = file_get_contents('http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $str;
?>
```

The above php code will read the json from http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/ and provide as shown below

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        .
        .
  ]
}
```

And I am receiving the response in android app and displaying the same in my android app.

Basically I am following http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ tutorial.

My query is what needs to be done in php file to compress the json and also how to decompress the same thing in my android app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is your purpose of "compress"?

Say bandwidth, there may cost many effort to pay for the very little effect on size changes (say 0.1/1kb) but you can still try to [enable gzip.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php)

```
<?php ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); ?>
```

Say security, it should be "encrypt".Then you should take a look with symetric encryption.

Comment: the main purpose to compress, is to save bandwidth.

    <?php 
    error_reporting(0);
    $str = file_get_contents('http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
    echo $str;
   ?>

Comment: Thanks. I am checking this and once I get full solution, I will update here.